# Facebook app invitation through Windows 8 metro app

Tags: windows, facebook, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I created a metro app. In this app I pick friends to an event and automatically send them a Facebook notification through my Facebook app which is connected to my metro app.

The problem is the fact that Facebook doesn't allow me to send notificatios to users who didn't have my Facebook app installed.

I've read that I can send them a Facebook invitation instead of notification.

I used the code Facebook provided but it dosn't work.

FacebookInvitationTest.js:

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
     <script>
         FB.init({
             appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
             oauth: true,
             frictionlessRequests: true,
             status: true,
             cookie: true,
             xfbml: true
         });

         function sendRequestToRecipients(user_ids) {
             FB.ui({
                 method: 'apprequests',
                 message: 'My Great Request',
                 to: user_ids
             }, requestCallback);
         }

         function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
             FB.ui({
                 method: 'apprequests',
                 message: 'My Great Request'
             }, requestCallback);
         }

         function requestCallback(response) {
             // Handle callback here
         }

        window.addEventListener('message', recievedMessage, false);

        function recievedMessage(e) {
            var friendIds = e.data;
            sendRequestToRecipients(friendIds);
        }
```

I get here but nothing happened. I put this file as an iframe in other file. I must do it in Windows 8.

How can I get the pop up window for sending invitations?

Comment: does this same code work in a plain web environment? no exceptions? nothing in console?

Comment: I tried it on Windows 7, but unfortunately nothing happenned. On Windows 8 i debugged this code and i really reach to the right place without any error, but still nothing happaned. I am asking how can i send app invitations to my friends who didn't install the app... If you have any other idea you welcome....